# Error en llenado de cuadro mediante bucle de una macro VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Buenas tardes estimados,

La siguiente macro me arroja error al iniciar el séptimo if que dice `If Range("H" & (i)) = "COM CHACAO" Then` , no entiendo por qué, si desactivo ese bucle anidado si corren los otros dos... por favor si pueden aclararme o darme alguna alternativa se los agradecería

```
For i = 1 To 100
    'CHACAO
    Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select
    If Range("B" & (i)) = "     LOIN" Then
        If Range("H" & (i)) = "COM CHACAO" Then
            If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then
                C9 = C9 + 1
            End If
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then
                D9 = D9 + 1
            End If
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then
                E9 = E9 + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Range("B" & (i)) = "     TRA5" Then
        If Range("H" & (i)) = "COM CHACAO" Then
            If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then
                G9 = G9 + 1
            End If
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then
                H9 = H9 + 1
            End If
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then
                I9 = I9 + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Range("B" & (i)) = "     TRA8" Then
        If Range("H" & (i)) = "COM CHACAO" Then
            If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then
                K9 = K9 + 1
            End If
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then
                L9 = L9 + 1
            End If
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then
                M9 = M9 + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
    Sheets("C").Select
    Range("C9").Value = C9
    Range("D9").Value = D9
    Range("E9").Value = E9
    Range("G9").Value = G9
    Range("H9").Value = H9
    Range("I9").Value = I9
    Range("K9").Value = K9
    Range("L9").Value = L9
    Range("M9").Value = M9
```

Ese segundo bucle anidado es una copia tal cual de los otros dos bucles, con la variación en lo que se verifica en la columna "B", no hallo la falla

---

Para ser más preciso, el error está en este bucle:

```
If Range("B" & (i)) = "     TRA5" Then
    If Range("H" & (i)) = "COM CHACAO" Then
        If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then
            G9 = G9 + 1
        End If
        If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then
            H9 = H9 + 1
        End If
        If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then
            I9 = I9 + 1
        End If
    End If
End If
```

---

Creo haber hallado el origen de la falla... al menos ya corre la macro sin errores, toca hacerle varias pruebas a ver

¿Cuál era la aparente falla?
Pues, la mcaro estaba bien, lo que sucedía es que al ir a extraer los datos de origen, dentro de ellos habían valores numéricos y algunos #N/A, cosa que generaba alguna discrepancia al compararlo con "COM CHACAO"

Seguiré haciendo pruebas y cualquier cosa les aviso

Comment: yo le recomiendo que utilice casos es mucho mas ordenado y previene equivocaciones

Comment: ¿? Si da un ejemplo le entendería mejor su punto de vista

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Comment: Se ha producido el error '13' en tiempo de ejecución:

No coinciden los tipos

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a SO. El principio de tu código se podría reducir. Cuando se utiliza la secuencia de IF...THEN...ELSE...END IF, si no hay ELSE y lo de dentro es una única línea, se puede escribir todo en la misma línea, y además omitir el END IF del final, y así escribimos menos código.

Un ejemplo. Tú has escrito lo siguiente:

```
If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then
     I9 = I9 + 1
End IF
```

Y sin embargo, como no tiene ELSE y lo de dentro es solamente una línea, podemos resumirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then I9 = I9 + 1
```

Y funcionará perfectamente.

Así que aplicado a tu código, podríamos hacer:

```
Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select
For i = 1 To 100
    'CHACAO
    If Range("H" & (i)) = "COM CHACAO" Then
        If Range("B" & (i)) = "     LOIN" Then
            If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then C9 = C9 + 1
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then D9 = D9 + 1
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then E9 = E9 + 1
        End If
        If Range("B" & (i)) = "     TRA5" Then
            If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then G9 = G9 + 1
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then H9 = H9 + 1
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then I9 = I9 + 1
        End If
        If Range("B" & (i)) = "     TRA8" Then
            If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then K9 = K9 + 1
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then L9 = L9 + 1
            If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then M9 = M9 + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Mucho más compacto. Fíjate que he hecho algunos cambios:

1. He puesto `Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select` fuera del bucle FOR...NEXT porque no necesitas activar la hoja en cada comprobación (tal cual es tu código). ¿Para qué activar la hoja 100 veces si en ningún momento cambias de hoja durante el bucle? Así que la sacamos del bucle y ahorramos tiempo de ejecución.
2. Haces varias comprobaciones, y una de ellas es común a todas, que es `If Range("H" & (i)) = "COM CHACAO"`. En cualquiera de los 3 casos que planteas, siempre compruebas luego esa condición. Al ser común a los 3, entonces la podemos sacar fuera. ¿Para qué comprobar si la celda en columna B es igual a `LOIN` o `TRA5` o `TRA8` si luego compruebas el valor de la columna H, y **si no es** `COM CHACAO` no vas a hacer nada? Pues esa condición común a los 3 casos, es lo primero que debes comprobar. Por eso es mi primer IF. Si se cumple, entonces ya comprobar cuál de las 3 opciones es.

Formular con IF...THEN en general es bastante más sencillo, pero si son muchos datos o la macro es larga, consume más tiempo con tu estructura actual. Esto es porque aunque un IF cumpla la condición, el código sigue leyendo el resto de IFS.

Un ejemplo. Supongamos que se cumple lo de `COM CHACAO` y lo de `LOIN`. El código incrementará los valores de C9,D9 y E9, pero también ejecutará el resto de IFS, aunque ya sepamos que no se cumple. No entrará hasta dentro porque no cumple la condición principal, pero los leerá, consumiendo tiempo.

PAra evitar esto, se puede utilizar el SELECT CASE, que sí es excluyente. Una vez que se elige una opción, ignora el resto del código, dentro de su Select. Toda la información la tienes en:

> **[Instrucción Select...Case (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)**

La ventaja del SELECT CASE sobre el IF THEN es que, aparte de permitirte plantear varias opciones sin tener que concatenar un IF con otro, es que una vez que se cumple la condición, excluye el resto del código, y no lo ejecuta, ahorrando tiempo de ejecución. Además, añadir nuevos escenarios es mucho más fácil en un SELECT CASE que en un END IF (que al final se hacen eternos)

Tu código con SELECT CASE quedaría algo así:

```
Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select
For i = 1 To 100 Step 1
    If Range("H" & i).Value = "COM CHACAO" Then
    Select Case Range("B" & i).Value
            Case "     LOIN"
                Select Case Range("D" & i).Value
                    Case Is <= 25
                        C9 = C9 + 1
                    Case 26 To 45
                        D9 = D9 + 1
                    Case Is >= 46
                        E9 = E9 + 1
                End Select
            Case "     TRA5"
                Select Case Range("D" & i).Value
                    Case Is <= 25
                        G9 = G9 + 1
                    Case 26 To 45
                        H9 = H9 + 1
                    Case Is >= 46
                        I9 = I9 + 1
                End Select
            Case "     TRA8"
                Select Case Range("D" & i).Value
                    Case Is <= 25
                        K9 = K9 + 1
                    Case 26 To 45
                        L9 = L9 + 1
                    Case Is >= 46
                        M9 = M9 + 1
                End Select
            Case Else
                'Si no hay coincidencias, hará lo que se ponga aquí. Útil para detectar errores
        End Select
    End If
Next i
```

Volvamos al ejemplo anterior. Supongamos que se cumple lo de `COM CHACAO` y lo de `LOIN`. El código incrementará los valores de C9,D9 y E9, pero nisiquiera leerá el resto de Select porque ya ha encontrado una coincidencia. Saltará directamente al final del bucle y siguiente incremento de `i`. Con grandes conjuntos de datos salva tiempo.

Yo he forzado varios Select Case para que puedas ver la estructura y sus posibilidades, pero personalmente suelo combinar ambos. Si solo tengo 2 opciones, suelo utilizar un IF..Then. Más de 2 posibilidades, o si veo que tengo que escribir varios IF then seguidos, suelo usar Select Case.

Así que mi código final lo dejaría de la siguiente manera (una combinación de ambos):

```
Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select
For i = 1 To 100 Step 1
    If Range("H" & i).Value = "COM CHACAO" Then
        Select Case Range("B" & i).Value
            Case "     LOIN"
                If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then C9 = C9 + 1
                If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then D9 = D9 + 1
                If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then E9 = E9 + 1
            Case "     TRA5"
                If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then G9 = G9 + 1
                If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then H9 = H9 + 1
                If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then I9 = I9 + 1
            Case "     TRA8"
                If Range("D" & (i)) <= 25 Then K9 = K9 + 1
                If Range("D" & (i)) >= 26 And Range("D" & (i)) <= 45 Then L9 = L9 + 1
                If Range("D" & (i)) >= 46 Then M9 = M9 + 1
            Case Else
                    'Si no hay coincidencias, hará lo que se ponga aquí. Útil para detectar errores
        End Select
    End If
Next i
```

Bien, y sobre tu pregunta, por lo que he leído has encontrado el error. Resulta que una fórmula en la columna H devuelve un error, y por eso no puede hacer la comparación. Es justo como tú dices.

Para detectar errores en tiempo de ejecución, VBA tiene una función incorporada, llamada ISERROR, que permite detectar si la celda tiene un valor erróneo.

> **[Función IsError](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function)**

Esta función booleana devolverá `True` si el valor de la celda es un error. Entonces, antes de ejecutar tu código, simplemente comprueba que la celda esté bien. Si tiene un error, que se detenga el código, que te avise de la fila con errores, lo corrijes y vuelves a reiniciar la macro. Por ejemplo, así:

```
For i = 1 To 100 Step 1
    If IsError(Range("B" & i).Value) = True Or IsError(Range("D" & i).Value) = True Or IsError(Range("H" & i).Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Error en fila " & i & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "La macro se detendrá", vbCritical, "ERROR"
        End
    End If
' Resto de tu código
```

Espero que esto te ayude un poco. Ya nos contarás a ver qué tal.

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto le sirva pero a mi los casos me gustan mas por el orden que le da a mi codigo

```
Select Case mi_expresion

Case mi_expresion_1
    'código para expresion_1

Case mi_expresion_2
    'código para expresion_2

'...

Case mi_expresion_n
    'código para expresion_n

Case Else
     'código para cuando no hay coincidencias
```

End Select

de esta forma podria ordenar y descartar su error nada pierde con intentarlo

Comment: Solo veo su aplicabilidad en los tres bucles internos que comparan el valor de una celda.


Para los dos bucles externos, no veo la forma de aplicarle el Case Select... y precisamente el error está en uno de los bucles externos

Answer (score -1):

Creo haber hallado el origen de la falla... al menos ya corre la macro sin errores, toca hacerle varias pruebas a ver

¿Cuál era la aparente falla?
Pues, la mcaro estaba bien, lo que sucedía es que al ir a extraer los datos de origen, dentro de ellos habían valores numéricos y algunos #N/A, cosa que generaba alguna discrepancia al compararlo con "COM CHACAO"

Seguiré haciendo pruebas y cualquier cosa les aviso